# Java String to bit array

Tags: java, arrays, string, bit

Considering the following `String`

```
String hexData = "1E01";
```

Is there a **simple** implementation to turn any `hexData` into a bit-based String array, like

```
String hexDataBits = "0001111000000001";
```

?

Comment: Why would "1E01" convert to "00001111000000001"? Did you mean "0001111000000001"

Comment: "0001111000000001"; fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. Convert your hex string to an int value using the built in parseInt function, then turn that into a binary string.

```
public String hexToBinary(String hexBits) {
    int intversion = Integer.parseInt(hexBits, 16);
    String binaryVers = Integer.toBinaryString(intversion);
    return binaryVers;
}
```

Note that this is not padded. If you want to pad it, modify `binaryVers`.

eg:

```
// if you're dead set on having at least 16 chars, put this before the return statement
int padding = 16 - binaryVers.length();
while (padding > 0) {
    binaryVers = "0" + binaryVers;
    padding--;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was dead set on having 16 chars. Thank you sir!

Comment: @Machado Keep in mind that if the hex # gets large enough 16 chars may not be enough to contain it... in which case it won't be formatted to be exactly 16, and you'll get more than 16 characters.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind! But for now I assume there will be no problems, since the bit arrays won't pass this limit.